# Execute an exe on unzipping the zip

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, exe, unzip

In our project i want to zip some files. The files include an exe and a text file.
Now what i need is to zip the file programatically.

Actually the exe need to run on the client machine and the text file contains some information that needed to run this exe.

So after after downloading it and on unzipping it need to execute the exe automatically.

Is there any way to do these things.

Comment: You're looking for a way to zip, unzip or both?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do what others normally use an installer package for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want a ZIP file whose contents will be magically executed once the ZIP is downloaded. Luckily this is not possible due to both technical and organizational reasons.

On the other hand, you can create platform-specific (i.e. Windows-only or Linux-only) self-extracting executable which will unpack its contents and start predefined file. This is what WinZIP does (IIRC Microsoft used such archives for their PowerToys deployment).

Comment: yes, how can i create a self extracting package with c#.net. Any useful links?

Comment: @mahesh There exist third-party ZIP components that do this. Our SecureBlackbox (http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-zip.php) supports creation of self-extracting archives. But self-extracting archives are EXE files which contain ZIP inside. They are not ZIPs themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own project(Winforms/WPF) in which you unzip files using `DotNetZip` Library. Code in that project so that when zip file is unzipped it run unzipped exe using `Process` command.

Allow user to download this project exe and zip file.

Comment: Actually the zip will be downloaded from a website. After downloading the zip file and on unzipping can we do it to automatically start executing the exe in it..?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you might be interested in [Self-extracting - SFX](http://74.cz/en/make-sfx/)

Comment: how can i create a self extracting package in c#.net?

Comment: Several links show how to proceed: 1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339768/Flexible-self-extracting-application-in-Csharp-Pro 2. http://www.componentace.com/sfx-zip-c-sharp.htm 3. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/a4315f1e-fb48-4ac5-9a6d-5397d7e24694